# using hidutil to map two keys to a single key

Tags: keyboard, mapping

I've lost the functionality of my `]` on my keyboard. Previously I used Karabiner to map `[ + option` to `]`, however now that I've updated to Sierra, this doesn't work.

I've seen this post: [How do I remap a key in macOS Sierra, e.g., Right Alt to Right Control?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control/283253#)

However is there a way to map 2 keys to a single key using `hidutil property`?

Specifically, I'd like to map `[ + option` to `]`

I've tried a few iterations including:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping": [{["HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x70000002f "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x7000000e2], "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000030}]}'
```

and

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping": [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":[0x70000002f, 0x7000000e2], "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000030}]}'
```

Neither of these worked

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: You can still run two separate commands.

Answer (score 1):

There's a third-party application called BetterTouchTool that will let you do this (and a *ton* more) quite easily.  Unfortunately, it's no longer a free app. However, it's an amazing app that's worth far more than it costs if you ask me.

For the record, no, I'm not related to the product in any way.  To the contrary, I'm a long-time paying customer who donated long before the dev started charging for it. At this point its so critical to my daily use on a Mac I feel completely lost without it.)