# How do I remap function modifier combinations?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I would like to remap the key binding `Shift+Option+7` (⇧⌥ 7) for the backward-slash `\` to something much simpler like `Option+.` (⌥ **.**) perhaps using a [command line tool like `hdiutil`.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299573)

The [answer to "*How do I remap a key in macOS Sierra, e.g., Right Alt to Right Control?*"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283253/300463) is quite clear about the guidelines provided in [Apple's Technical Note TN2450](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html). However, what is not clear to me is what the hex value is for characters typed using combinations of function modifier keys. I am running macOS Mojave on a 2018 MBP13 with German keyboard layout.

Can somebody tell me how I should proceed?

Comment: Making a custom layout that does what you want takes a couple minutes with the Ukelele app.

Comment: PS Here is one   https://www.dropbox.com/s/f66ei6e24fvqjx8/German2.keylayout?dl=0