# Logitech MX Keys: sleep mode keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, hardware, shortcut

I am using the Logitech MX Keys which is great.

[image: Logitech MX Keys]

Since there is no Eject/Power key I [miss some shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236), specifically Option–Command–Media Eject.

Is there a way to put my Mac to Sleep mode with this keyboard?

Comment: If you don't have an Eject key, you'll have to remap Eject to one that does exist.  See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323369/remap-eject-key-to-backslash

Comment: This keyboard layout is both non-US but the top row has the same physical keys as the MX version for macOS which has a properly labeled (and functioning) media eject key where this has an unlabeled “F13” key with a speaker stencil on it. I wonder if you could get that mapped precisely in software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Sleep exists as a menu command, you could make your own…

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

Select All Applications, press the  <kbd>+</kbd>  button, type Sleep then pick a key command - I'd pick something hard to do by accident, like maybe  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

<sup>I used D in the example image, because I already have S used for Shutdown</sup>

Comment: Great! For some reason, I had to put to sleep mode manually first to activate the shortcut...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why, but on my side, neither the solution above (maybe because I run French OSX?) nor [some other options](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406683/how-to-put-macbook-to-sleep-using-only-an-attached-windows-keyboard) work well for me.

Anyway, I came with another solution using the Logitech Options application which allows to customize the keys with the actions of your choice. Out of the box, sleep is not available as action in the software of Logitech. But with a very simple Applescript, the magic can happen.

Full solution:

- open the applescript editor
- create a new script with 1 line : do shell script "pmset sleepnow"
- export it as an application (File > Export - then select File format = application)
- open Logitech Options and customize the key of your choice to launch the application that you just created

I hope it can help.

Comment: This is an excellent solution - I’ve had to use it on occasion when [other options were too heavy weight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28164/) or [just didn’t work.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406683/)

Answer (score 1):

If you press the "lock" button top right on the full keyboard and perhaps "fn" + "lock" button on the mini keyboard to lock the screen. And then when the screen is locked press "esc" top left button I think it's the same thing as putting it to sleep?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new short cut just for putting your Mac into sleep mode you can also press the <kbd>Lock</kbd> and then the <kbd>ESC</kbd> button afterwards. Locks and then cancels logging in = Sleep