# How to put MacBook to sleep using only an attached Windows keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake, power-management

I have a new MacBook Pro that I leave plugged in and closed because I use an external display, keyboard, and mouse.

My monitor, keyboard, and mouse are also used by my PC.

When I'm finished with work, I'd like to be able to easily sleep the Mac so that my monitor can automatically switch over to my home PC.

[Apple docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) say:

> Option–Command–Power button* or Option–Command–Media Eject : Put your Mac to sleep

But my Windows keyboard doesn't have a "Media Eject" or "Power" button on it.

What are my other options for easily putting my Mac to sleep?

I already know I could use the mouse to click Apple > Sleep. And I could open the lid and use the power button. But I'd prefer a keyboard command.

Comment: The power button is not on the keyboard, but on the top case -that answer from Apple assumes you're using the built in keyboard on the laptop or you're using an Apple keyboard.  Alternatively, you could create a simple (Terminal) script with the single command `pmset sleepnow` then just double click it when you want to sleep your computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the **Sleep** *command* on the **Apple** menu a *keyboard shortcut* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts**

**Notes:**

- On a **Windows** *keyboard* the *Windows logo key* is the **⌘** *key*.
- **System Preferences** may first need to be closed for the *keyboard shortcut* to take affect.

[image]

[image]

You can assign any unused key combination (like <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>) using `System Preferences` » `Keyboard` » `Keyboard Shortcuts` » `Application Shortcuts`.
Click the `+` button. Leave "Application" set as "All Applications". For `Menu Title`, write `Sleep`, and under `Keyboard Shortcut`, press

Comment: Thank you to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28168/53510 for extra clarity.