# Sleep keyboard shortcut on M1 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, shortcut, apple-silicon

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> shortcut to put the computer to sleep does not work on the M1 MacBook Pro (assuming that the Touch ID button replaces the power button).

What is the keyboard shortcut to put the M1 MacBook Pro to sleep?

Comment: Don't know what the built-in _keyboard shortcut_ is, however, you can also add one of your own.  Have a look at my answer: [How to put MacBook to sleep using only an attached Windows keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406683/how-to-put-macbook-to-sleep-using-only-an-attached-windows-keyboard/406689#406689)

Answer (score 28):

This bothered me too. I have hot corners active, but have three screens connected to my MacBook Pro, and that is quite a distance to travel.

There is a simpler solution, without the need for third party tools.
Goto `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` under the tab `Shortcuts` select `App Shortcuts` in the left column and then click the `plus button`. In the dialog box use `Sleep` (or the equivalent to your "Sleep" in your OS language - just check the Apple menu item) for the "Menu Title" field and select a free shortcut.

You will then find it is listed under the  menu.

[image: Create a new shortcut]
[image: The shortcut can be seen in the Apple menu]

Comment: This answer seems to actually put it to sleep. Perfect, thanks

Comment: I used Shift-F6 since that key already shows the moon symbol :-)

Comment: OMG this is so what I was looking for. I didn't know you can enter a keyboard shortcut from menu entry name. Thanks !

Comment: Doesn't work for external USB keyboard by some reason

Comment: @Nic it does work for me with an external keyboard (MBP 2016, Monterey, 12.5.1). Make sure you use the exact name you see on the system menu. I had to add 2 shortcuts because I have the OS in Catalan and, depending on the language of the app I'm using, the system menu word is in English (Sleep) or Catalan (Repòs).

Comment: Amazing, thanks for sharing this! Have been struggling for a week to get my previous remapping to work on a new MacBook Pro, but this works perfectly!

Comment: I just registered to vote up this answer. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 19):

On my M1 MacBook Air, the following works: press Touch ID with any finger **not registered with Touch ID** to lock the Mac. Then press Esc to Sleep.

Comment: Does this truly put it to sleep though? I was using the same combination of actions, believing that it did. Today, after not touching my Air for 6 days I find that it's used about 12% battery every day over that period, and examining the logs with `pmset -g log | grep -E 'Wake from|Entering Sleep'` suggests it **never** actually went to sleep in all that time.

Comment: It probably puts the *display* to sleep, similar to the "hot corners" suggestion.

Comment: This seems to do the following:
- first put display to sleep
- if nothing is happening on computer (like playing music etc), then it does seem to put computer to sleep after half a minute or so
- if "anything relevant" is going on, then it will not force sleep as old shortcut did (Ctrl + Shift + Power), computer will stay active (visible on network / playing media etc.) with only display / external monitor turned off

Comment: Tried this multiple times, most of the time, this computer does not got to sleep and consume battery/power.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question on my MacBook Air M1, and was finally able to get it to work with [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). I've reassigned the *Do not Disturb  (F6)* function key to launch Sleep Mode. You can find the exact script I've used to import into Karabiner [here](https://genesy.github.io/karabiner-complex-rules-generator/#eyJ0aXRsZSI6IlNsZWVwIE1vZGUgd2l0aCBGdW5jdGlvbiBLZXkgKERvIE5vdCBEaXN0dXJiKSIsInJ1bGVzIjpbeyJkZXNjcmlwdGlvbiI6Ik1hcCBGNiAoRG8gTm90IERpc3R1cmIpIHRvIENtZCtPcHQrRWplY3QgZm9yIFNsZWVwIE1hYyIsIm1hbmlwdWxhdG9ycyI6W3siZnJvbSI6eyJrZXlfY29kZSI6ImY2In0sInR5cGUiOiJiYXNpYyIsInRvX2FmdGVyX2tleV91cCI6W3sicmVwZWF0IjpmYWxzZSwiY29uc3VtZXJfa2V5X2NvZGUiOiJlamVjdCIsIm1vZGlmaWVycyI6WyJsZWZ0X2d1aSIsImxlZnRfYWx0Il19XX1dfV19).

P.S. At first it actually kept waking up instantly with my Apple Watch, but after some trial and error got it to work perfectly by using the After_Key_Up event.

Hopefully this helps you and others!

Comment: Works perfectly for me, thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: I would actually recommend everyone [the solution above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/431149/404743) -- it's much cleaner and works perfectly for me to remap the _Do not Disturb _ function key to launch Sleep Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use automator to add a **Sleep** service

### Create a Automator service

1. Open **Automator**
2. New a Quick Action
   [image]
3. Add **Run Applescript**
   [image]
4. Replace the code as

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}
     tell application "System Events" to sleep
     return input
   end run
   ```
5. Save as `sleep`

### Bind the shortcut

1. Go to *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts*
2. In the side menu, *select Services > General > sleep*
3. Bind to any key you want

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that I can press the left side of my fingerprint sensor to sleep my mac screen. I can't press the middle because it will instantly unlock it from my fingerprint and the right side doesn't sleep it but both top left and bottom left put it to sleep. Figured I would share since I ended up here then found exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click Keyboard, click the Keyboard button, then click Customize Control Strip. Drag the Sleep button onto the Touch Bar.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't a keyboard shortcut, I have had success using the 'Hot Corners' feature to put the device to sleep: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-hot-corners-mchlp3000/mac

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Siri** to do this. It might look silly but it is kinda effective. It is the only thing I use it for actually.

Just hold <kbd>F5</kbd> button for a sec (the one with microphone) to activate  Siri and say "Sleep please".

This worked for me for over a year. Yesterday however Siri was stubborn and started to telling me *she* could not sleep. After repeating the input she told me "Zzz Zzz Zzz" and stuff . Then I said "Put the macbook to sleep" and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- `control` + `command` + `q` is likely the easiest option.
- Others have mentioned the "[Hot Corners Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-hot-corners-mchlp3000/mac)" option in the Desktop & Dock section of System Settings.
- If you work in the terminal a lot, `pmset displaysleepnow` will do it. You'll likely want to create an alias for that.