# Change left Cmd key to Ctrl Key wihout changing the right Cmd key in Macbook Pro High Sierra?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, keybindings

I have two command keys on my MacBook Pro(High Sierra). I often use control with my pinky finger. Is it possible to map only right Cmd key with control key while the left Cmd key should function as it is? It would really help in removing the strain from pinky finger.

P.S.
I looked at the solution of [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control) and found that the [specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) is not only outdated but doesn't contain the hex code for right and left command keys.

I also tried the following command by using key code from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h file but it still doesn't works

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":
[{
    "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000036,
    "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x70000003b}]
}'
```

Comment: Right or left key?

Comment: Please clarity if you are looking to map just one of the two Command keys to Control key or both of them. Also, resolve the ambiguity as to which Command key you are referring to, right or left?

Comment: @NimeshNeema are we to assume the “normal” meaning of left & right?

Comment: @SolarMike Please define normal in this context.

Comment: @Allan Can you please remove it from duplicate as the similar question doesn't answer my question.