# How to remap right Control key to Command/apple key?

Tags: keyboard, mojave

Similar question [over here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control) does not provide an answer.

[tn2450](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) gives no option to address apple/command key.

System settings do not allow to remap only right Control key.

Is there a way to make right-Control key to act like Command key while leaving left-Control alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) should be able to do that for you.

If this is a USB device, you might be able to do use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) too.

Comment: Karabiner is free and it solved the issue for me!