# Magic Keyboard with number pad: type comma instead of a dot

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm using Magic Keyboard 2 with numeric keypad. The problem I have is that when I use English US as input source, the dot on the numpad results in " . "

Where I'd need it to type a comma (as in, e.g., German language). I need comma, because I live in Europe, and the number separator for decimals is "," and not a ".". And all calculations are made with comma.

[image: Numpad]

Comment: You can remap the key.  See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283252/119271

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System Preferences- Language and Region- at the bottom of the box click "Advanced"- then choose the dot/ comma under Number separators- Decimal and again under drop down box "decimal" under currency.

Answer (score 6):

I know it is an old question, but for those like me who changed decimals to comma just to find out it did nothing, you can use this approach.

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping": [{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc": 0x700000063, "HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst": 0x700000036}]}'
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html

It replaces the , from the keypad to . It can be reverted changing the values 0x7... but anyway, IMO comma should be the key by default, as it is the most common decimal separator.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg

Comment: Does this approach still work? I can't get this to work with Ventura. The `hidutil` command, when run like above, outputs some mappings, but the numeric keypad is unchanged.

Comment: For me (German keyboard), I had map from `0x7...63` to `0x7...37`to show a dot when I press the numeric keypad dot/comma key.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a custom layout with comma instead of dot on that key [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19fmo6nfgsup4p0/US%20Comma.zip?dl=0).