# How do I remap keys in Mac OS high sierra

Tags: keyboard

So I would want to swap the keys y and z with each other, is there anyway to remap the keys with something like a terminal command

Comment: This has been asked a number of times.  How about this Q/A:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control/283253#283253

Comment: What is your purpose in asking this? If you want to have qwertz instead of qwerty, just activate the German keyboard in system preferences.

Comment: Well I don't want the entire qwertz layout I just want to swap z  and y, if I switch to the qwertz layout it changes more than z and y