# In iTerm2 map the left Command key to the left Control key & map Command+Tab

Tags: terminal, iterm, keybindings

In iTerm2, can I map the left <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key to the left <kbd>^ Control</kbd>
key **and** still map the system <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> to still switch to all other windows?

I've use three different OS's (Ubuntu, macOS and Windows) regular and my subconscious is constantly wanting to switch windows using <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>⇨Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

While not answering the question I have discovered the following work around in the meantime for my most commonly used terminal "control+" inputs:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - clear terminal line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - reverse search

Set the remap modifiers in iTerm to default:

[image: Remap modifiers in iTerm]

Set the keybindings for <kbd>Command</kbd>+R, etc. to "Send Hex codes:" and enter the hex codes from http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php as follows:

[image]

And viola it works for <kbd>Command</kbd>+R = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+R as required....to do the entire alphabet would require mapping multiple hex codes

Comment: How do you copy text from your terminal?

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, it can be set in iTerm's *Preferences → Keys → Remap Modifiers*

[image: Keys Remap Modifier]

#### Next, in the same Preferences Pane, select *Key Bindings Tab*.

From there, you will see all the currently defined key bindings.  If Control-Tab isn't defined you can create a new one, however this is a clean install and this is what's shown by default.

[image: iTerm Key Bindings Tab]

#### Double click on the "Action" description to modify the behavior.

It will bring up a (long) list of actions you can assign to the keybinding. (I selected "Cycle Tabs Forward")

[image: iTerm Key Bindings Sub Menu]

This will configure iTerm to accept the left <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> as <kbd>^ Control</kbd> and is limited to iTerm only.  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> still works, but within iTerm you *must* use the right <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>.  Outside of iTerm, everything will function as normal.

If you're using Catalina, you will  have to give Accessibility permissions to iTerm under *System Settings → Security & Privacy → Privacy Tab → Accessibility* if you haven't already done so.

Comment: @TimWiel - take a look at this question/answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283252/119271

Comment: Thanks @Allan I have done this however unfortunately your answer is responding to half the question sorry. Because the left command is now mapped to Control the standard system command of Command+Tab still doesn't work as expected because it is now sending Control+Tab to iTerm so doesn't switch windows.

I suspect I need to map the Control+Tab keybinding to Command+Tab and it might work - anywhere I can do this??

Comment: The  apple.stackexchange.com/q/283252/119271 link seems to be system wide remap - not just for iTerm - I still want left command to remain as is in every other application except iTerm - thanks!

Comment: Do you want Control-Tab to go through the tabs  *within* iTerm?

Comment: So to clarify I have mapped, in iTerm, the command key to control and mapped the control key to left command. Therefore to go **from** iTerm to Google Chrome I need to push control+tab _but_ to go back **to** iTerm **from** Google Chome I need to push command+tab (which is mac system default). However I want I really want is that command+tab in iterm switches to Google Chome **but** yet command+c or command+r (and so on) is still be mapped to control+c or control+r (and so on)....

Comment: In my case I just HATE where the CTRL key is on Macs I wanted the right ⌘ key to be CTRL in iterm2.