# Quick typing not possible after key remap

Tags: keyboard, catalina, keybindings

I followed the tips in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control) thread. The [TN2450](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) remaps the keys correctly, but a new problem has surfaced: The keys do not register when pressing more of them at the same time. Example: If typing the letters `f` and `t` fast after eachother, the `t` does not register if it is pressed too early. The `f` key has to be completely let go before pressing the `t` key. The problem can be replicated by holding the `f` key down while quickly press the `t` key multiple times. The first press does not register, but all the following presses does. The problem does not regard all remapped keys. The problem is not symmetric; the order of the keypresses matter. Problematic combinations:
ft
pø
ke
gd
jn
ul
yj
li
rp
sr
tg
ds
nk
ef
iu
oy

ok. I see the pattern now: If the old version of the key is pressed after the new version of itself, it does not work. Is there some infinite loop problem going on?

The problem is present on both the Macbook keyboard and the external Magic keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your problem may be with keyboard, not software.  But worth a try is the following. Go to system preferences / Keyboard and click on keyboard tab.  see image below.

[image]

There is a slider to adjust the delay time between keys. Make that time as short as possible.  This feature is for holding down a key and having it repeat but should work in your case too.