# How to remap "right option" key to "control + option + command + shift" in Karabiner?

Tags: mac, keyboard, catalina, karabiner

This is my first experience with the mac app Karabiner.
I was wondering how to map following key:
right_command = shift + alt + ctrl + cmd?

## NOTE:

There is one macro already available for caps-lock to bind it to shift+alt+cmd+ctrl.

But, I would like to get the combination for right command, since cap-lock is useful when I have to type acronyms like NVM, AKS, ASAP and so on.

Comment: There are ***lots*** of existing questions/answers on how to remap keys with Karabiner.  Here’s just one example:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283252/119271  Which have you tried and what were you’re results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the karabiner json file:
`~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`

Look for this part in your profile:

```
"complex_modifications": {
    "rules": [ ]
}
```

Then add a new rule:

```
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "description": "Change right option to command+control+option+shift.",
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "right_option",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "optional": [
                                            "any"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "left_command",
                                        "modifiers": [
                                            "left_control",
                                            "left_option",
                                            "left_shift"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Restart the karabiner, it should work now.