# How do I customize my external keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I just got a new Mac from my employer and it has a Dutch keyboard layout.

[image]

The main difference is the location of the backtick ` and it has a non-standard key §/± at the location of the backtick in other layouts that I am more used to.

99% of the time I use it as a desktop and work with big monitors and external keyboards
and first I don't want to buy new keyboards.

My old keyboards have a quite universal layout like

[image]

I need to do a lot of work in R and python so I need to use the backtick very often. However, it seems not possible to enter backtick with my Dutch mac. When I click that backtick on my external keyboard, it returns the § as the same location on my internal keyboard. I did the keyboard setting but the default did not help.

I don't need that §/± key.

Can you help me make the backtick key on my external keyboard produce the real backtick character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remap a key in macOS Sierra, e.g., Right Alt to Right Control?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control)

Comment: macOS allows multiple languages and input sources. What languages and keyboard layouts do you have active? The images you generated are nice, however Apple has a keyboard viewer you can see what is actually mapped at the moment. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-input-sources-settings-mchl84525d76/mac (Keyboard Viewer is available when you show input sources in the menu bar)

Comment: When you press the key left of Z, do you not get a backtick?  Your old keyboards were of the ANSI type, used in N and S America and Asia.  Your new keyboard is the ISO type, used in all of Europe, Middle East, and Africa.

Comment: For a custom layout that should put the backtick at the upper left on an ISO keyboard, you can try https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/b4lfx25df9e75u26y6dkx/US-ISO-High-Tilde.bundle.zip?rlkey=sn77fykb31t8wldxm2xsaae54&dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Try using Keyboard Setup Assistant.

1. Apple logo > System Preferences (System Settings)
2. Keyboard > Change Keyboard Type (bottom right)
3. Follow the on-screen instructions.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I don’t think that will help.  He already has the right “type”, he just doesn’t like where that type has the backtick key.